# Create dynamic blacklist with nftables

Tags: linux, ssh, firewall, nftables

I want to create a dynamic blacklist with nftables. Under version 0.8.3 on the embedded device I create a ruleset looks like this with nft list ruleset:

```
table inet filter {
set blackhole {
    type ipv4_addr
    size 65536
    flags timeout
}

chain input {
    type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
    ct state invalid drop
    ct state established,related accept
    iif "lo" accept
    ip6 nexthdr 58 icmpv6 type { destination-unreachable, packet-too-big, time-exceeded, parameter-problem, echo-request, echo-reply, mld-listener-query, mld-listener-report, mld-listener-done, nd-router-solicit, nd-router-advert, nd-neighbor-solicit, nd-neighbor-advert, ind-neighbor-solicit, ind-neighbor-advert, mld2-listener-report } accept
    ip protocol icmp icmp type { echo-reply, destination-unreachable, echo-request, router-advertisement, router-solicitation, time-exceeded, parameter-problem } accept
    ip saddr @blackhole counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
    tcp flags syn tcp dport ssh meter flood { ip saddr timeout 1m limit rate over 10/second burst 5 packets}  set add ip saddr timeout 1m @blackhole drop
    tcp dport ssh accept
}

chain forward {
    type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
}

chain output {
    type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
}
}
```

For me this is only a temporary solution. I want to use the example from the official [manpage](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/nftables/manpage.html) for dynamic blacklisting. If I use the offical example from the manpage my nftables file looks like this:

```
table inet filter {
set blackhole{
        type ipv4_addr
        flags timeout
        size 65536
}
chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;

        # drop invalid connections
        ct state invalid drop

        # accept traffic originating from us
        ct state established,related accept

        # accept any localhost traffic
        iif lo accept

        # accept ICMP
        ip6 nexthdr 58 icmpv6 type { destination-unreachable, packet-too-big, time-exceeded, parameter-problem, echo-request, echo-reply, mld-listener-query, mld-listener-report, mld-listener-done, nd-router-solicit, nd-router-advert, nd-neighbor-solicit, nd-neighbor-advert, ind-neighbor-solicit, ind-neighbor-advert, mld2-listener-report } accept
        ip protocol icmp icmp type { destination-unreachable, router-solicitation, router-advertisement, time-exceeded, parameter-problem, echo-request, echo-reply } accept

        # accept SSH (port 22)
        ip saddr @blackhole counter drop
        tcp flags syn tcp dport ssh meter flood { ip saddr timeout 10s limit rate over 10/second} add @blackhole { ip saddr timeout 1m } drop
        tcp dport 22 accept

}


chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
}

chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
}

}
```

But when I load this nftables file on version 0.8.3 with nft -f myfile I get this error:

```
Error: syntax error, unexpected add, expecting newline or semicolon
    tcp flags syn tcp dport ssh meter flood { ip saddr timeout 10s limit rate over 10/second} add @blackhole { ip saddr timeout 1m } drop
```

I don't know why this is the case, but according to the [wiki](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Meters) it should work from version 0.8.1 and kernel 4.3.

I have version 0.8.3 and kernel 4.19.94.

I have tested under Debian Buster the ruleset from the official manpage with version 0.9.0. The ruleset from the manpage works fine with Debian, but the ip is blocked only once.

With this example I want to create a firewall rule which blocks the ip adress on ssh port if an brute force attack is started to my device. But I want to block the ip e.g for 5 minutes. After that time it should be possible to connect again to the device from the attackers ip. If he do brute force again it should be block the ip again for 5 minutes and so on. I want to avoid to use another software for my embedded device like sshguard or fail2ban if it is possible with nftables.

I hope anyone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: I made the reply in a new post. See below

Comment: When I start an attack on my embedded device with hydra, the ip address is blocked for one minute (hydra continues to run). After this minute the corresponding ip address is released and I can continue my desired brute force attack with hydra. But what I want is for nftables to detect that there is still a brute force attack running and then nftables will immediately lock the ip address. Hydra has only one ip address (the address of my pc)

Comment: I'll have to test what hydra is doing...

Comment: Thanks. Hydra is in the repository of Debian and Ubuntu. My command looks like this inline `hydra -l <username> -P </path/to/passwordlist.txt> -I -t 6 ssh://<ip-address>`

Comment: I think I addressed your issues in my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`hydra`](https://manpages.debian.org/hydra/hydra.1) tool connects concurrently multiple times to the SSH server. In OP's case  ([comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/581964/create-dynamic-blacklist-with-nftables?noredirect=1#comment1083930_581964): `hydra -l <username> -P </path/to/passwordlist.txt> -I -t 6 ssh://<ip-address>`) it will use 6 concurrent threads connecting.

Depending on server settings, one connection could typically try 5 or 6 passwords and taking about 10 seconds before being rejected by the SSH server, so I fail to see how a rate of 10 *connection* attempts per second could be exceeded (but that's the case). It could mean that what triggers is that more than 5 connection attempts are done in less than 1/2s. I wouldn't trust too much the accuracy of `10/s`, but it can be assumed it happens here.

### Version and syntax issues

The syntax not working with versions 0.8.1 or 0.8.3 is a newer syntax that appeared in [this commit](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/?id=e7395266640aed088e312ca1da3c147b64059988):

> src: revisit syntax to update sets and maps from packet path
>
> For sets, we allow this:
>
> ```
>   nft add rule x y ip protocol tcp update @y { ip saddr}
> ```
>
> [...]

It was committed *after* version 0.8.3 so available only with nftables >= 0.8.4

The current wiki revision for [Updating sets from the packet path](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php?title=Updating_sets_from_the_packet_path&oldid=480), in the same page, still displays commands with the former syntax

> ```
>  % nft add rule filter input set add ip saddr @myset
> ```
>
> [...]

and results displayed with the newer syntax:

> [...]
>
> ```
>                 add @myset { ip saddr }
> ```
>
> [...]

Some wiki pages or the latest manpage might not work with older nftables versions.

Anyway, if running with kernel 4.19, *nftables* >= 0.9.0 should be preferred to get additional features. For example it's available in [Debian 10](https://packages.debian.org/buster/nftables) or in [Debian 9 backports](https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/nftables).

### Blacklisting should be done before stateful accept rules

Once the IP is added to the blacklist, this doesn't prevent established connections to continue, unhindered and unaccounted, until they're disconnected by the SSH server itself. That's because there's the usual existing short-circuit rule before:

> ```
>         # accept traffic originating from us
>         ct state established,related accept
> ```

This comment is misleading: it doesn't *accept traffic originating from us* but *any traffic already ongoing*. This is a short-circuit rule. Its role is to handle stateful connections by parsing all rules only for new connections: any rule after this one applies to new connections. Once connections are accepted, their individual packets stay accepted until end of connection.

For the specific case of blacklist handling, specific blacklist rules or part of them should be placed before this short-circuit rule to be able to take effect immediately. In OP's case that is:

> ```
>         ip saddr @blackhole counter drop
> ```

It should be moved before the `ct state established,related accept` rule.

Now once the attacker is added to the blacklist, other ongoing connections won't get some remaining free attempts at guessing a password: they'll immediately hang.

### If there's a blacklist, consider a whitelist

As a side note, the cheap `iif lo accept` rule could itself be moved before both as an optimization and to be whitelisted: all (even long lived) local established connection will also now be subject to blacklisting in case of abuse (eg: from 127.0.0.1). Consider adding various whitelisting rules before the `@blackhole` rule.

### Optionally warn applications faster

To also prevent ongoing replies from server to reach the blacklisted IP (especially for UDP traffic, not that useful for TCP, including SSH), the equivalent rule using `daddr` can also be added in the `inet filter output` chain, with reject to inform faster the local processes trying to emit that they should abort:

```
    ip daddr @blackhole counter reject
```

### Difference between `add` and `update` applied on a set

Now with such settings in place, even if ongoing connections are immediately stopped, the attacker is able to keep trying and get a new short window 1mn later, which is not optimal.

The entries must be *update*d in the input `@blackhole ... drop` rule. `update` will refresh the timer if the entry already existed, while `add` would do nothing. This will keep blocking any further (unsuccessful) attempt to connect to the SSH server until attacker gives up, with zero opened window. (The output rule I added above shouldn't be changed, it's not the attacker's actions):

replace:

> ```
> ip saddr @blackhole counter drop
> ```

with (still keeping older syntax):

```
ip saddr @blackhole counter set update ip saddr timeout 1m @blackhole drop
```

It should even be moved before the `ct state invalid` rule, else if attacker tries invalid packets (eg TCP packet not part of a known connection, like a late RST from an already forgotten connection), the set won't be updated while it could have been.

### Limit the maximum number of established connections

Requires kernel >= 4.18 and nftables >= 0.9.0, so can't be done with OP's current configuration.

The attacker might discover it can't connect too many times at once but can still keep adding, without limit, new connections, as long as not connecting too fast.

A [limit on concurrent connections](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/?id=57e4a095edc4dab19e14fc8d1bca3febde1ca86c) (as available with iptables's [`connlimit`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#connlimit))  can also be added with an other meter rule:

```
tcp flags syn tcp dport 22 meter toomanyestablished { ip saddr ct count over 3 } reject with tcp reset
```

will allow any given IP address to have only 3 established SSH connections.

Or while at it, instead, also trigger the @blackhole set (using newer syntax this time):

```
tcp flags syn tcp dport 22 meter toomanyestablished { ip saddr ct count over 3 } add @blackhole { ip saddr timeout 1m } drop
```

This should trigger even before the previous meter rule in OP's case. Use with care to avoid legitimate users to be affected (but see openssh's [`ControlMaster`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh_config.5#ControlMaster) option).

### IPv4 and IPv6

As there's no generic IPv4+IPv6 set address type, all rules handling IPv4 (whenever there's the 2-letters word `ip`) should probably be duplicated into a mirror rule having `ip6` in them and working on an IPv6 set.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day. You got my problem solved. It works really well!

Comment: This is the kind of extremely informative answer that should be a model for all others. What many might consider the 'extra stuff' was phenomenally useful to me, and are very close natural follow-ups that saved me much additional searching for each point. I will post a separate question about an error performing the final recommended operation, and an answer there should probably lead to an edit here. Stay tuned.

Comment: Just as a side note, potentially `typeof ip <saddr|daddr>` (>0.9.4) for sets could do away with the requirement to have separate rules _and_ sets for IPv4 and IPv6. With good old `ipset` it was possible to create a set of sets (where the contained sets where IPv4 or IPv6 specific) and then update/insert elements to that "superset". It appears nftables is somewhat late learning that very useful trick, while otherwise it pretty much promises the ability to unify rules across IPv4 and IPv6.