# Prior to nftables 0.9.4 is there a way to express a set of sets to unify IPv4 and IPv6 rules?

Tags: ubuntu, nftables

[The documentation](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Sets) suggests that from `nftables` 0.9.4 on it's possible to use `typeof ip daddr` (and similar) to combine IPv4 and IPv6  sets. Alas, the LTS Ubuntu version 20.04 is one patch short of that version (0.9.3).

Quote:

> The `typeof` keyword is available since 0.9.4 and allows you to use a high level expression, then let nftables resolve the base type for you

In the past with `ipset` I created a set of sets whenever I wanted to refer only to a single name. So I had a set specific to IPv4 (e.g. `blackhole4`), another to IPv6 (e.g. `blackhole6`) and then one containing those two (e.g. `blackhole`). The in-packet-path as well as the `ipset` CLI updating of the set elements worked fine against that set of sets. The elements would be inserted/updated in the appropriate "subset".

**Is there a possibility to unify *sets* also for nftables 0.9.3?**

NB: I'd be fine having to create separate IPv4 and IPv6-specific sets and then have some container set to achieve the feat. It's just that given the documentation I don't see how to achieve this.

PS: I saw [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/581964/5462) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/586735/5462) but they were for other nftables versions *and* the outcome is not what's desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently as of 2021-05-01 no version of kernel and nftables (including 0.9.8) can do this.

Pablo Neira Ayuso, a lead developer wrote on 2020-09-26 there's no major architectural issue preventing its implementation, but it's not done yet.

https://www.spinics.net/lists/netfilter/msg59761.html :

> So you would like to consolidate:
>
> ```
> tcp dport @b_t update @b_sa4 { ip saddr } drop
> tcp dport @b_t update @b_sa6 { ip6 saddr } drop
> ```
>
> In one single rule?
>
> Something like (**hypothetical syntax**)
>
> ```
> tcp dport @b_t update @b_sa { inet saddr } drop
> ```
>
> where *b_sa* is a set with something like `type inet_addr`.

https://www.spinics.net/lists/netfilter/msg59761.html :

> General set infrastructure that provides an abstraction for IPv4 and
> IPv6 through inet is possible, yes.

Comment: Such a shame that something that was easily doable with `ipset` is no longer possible.